# What does slat and elat (slon, elon) in latitude and longitude values mean?

Tags: models

I have data from the national [storm prediction center](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/index.html) that is marked with values of :
elat 
slat
elon
slon

```
`slat        slon        elat        elon
`31.6671    -90.9352    31.6998     -90.8813
```

What do those values mean?
What does the "s" & "e" prefix stand for?

Answer (score 4):

This might be product specific, but if it's anything like my MODIS experience this refers to **s**tart and **e**nd latitude and longitude. Are you looking at a small region on the Mississippi/Louisiana border?

Comment: Thanks, you posted right after I did.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think I finally figured out what those values are.

The data is tornado data and I believe the slat, slon are **Start** locations (of the tornado) and the elat, elon are **End** locations for the tornado.

This only became apparent when I added those locations to a Google map and saw the distances.

Here is a [map with the two locations](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'31.6671,-90.9352'/31.699799985277465,+-90.8813000175732/@31.6813792,-90.9501063,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!4m8!1m3!2m2!1d-90.9352!2d31.6671!1m3!2m2!1d-90.8813!2d31.6998) on it (obviously the path is a driving path and not path of tornado, but it shows the distance).